# How to set string value in model using a dropdown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm working with an ASP.NET mvc projekt and I'm familiar with the usual razor helpers @Html.TextBoxFor... etc. but I'm in the situation where I need to set a string value in the model using a dropdown list, the list always has the same twelve items in it and I just need to populate this list with those items and make sure it sets the field value in the model to the selected one.

I'm curious how I should go about doing this? I've looked at dropdown tutorials and I might be able to get a dropdown working but I'm not sure how to set the field value and I'm not sure where to store these twelve strings. I thought about hardcoding them instead of putting them in a db or something since it's so few but I'm open to better suggestions.

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE

This is my Razor code, I created a simple viewmodel which contains the list of items to display in the dropdown and including the model class I wanna use for this create view.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.question.QuestionId, new SelectList(Model.AreasList), new { @class = "dropdown" })
```

This is my viewmodel

```
public class CreateQuestionViewModel
    {
        public Question question { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<String> AreasList = new List<String> { "Option 1", "Option 2" };

    }
```

It works but I can't figure out why visual studio keeps throwing me a null reference and points at my razor code for the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

sure, so you need to set the model field based on the selected List Item when the user selects it, assuming that you have a static dropdown list:

//this is your view View1.chtml

```
    @model Class1

        <select id="list1" name="list1">
            <option value="0">option1</option>
            <option value="1">option2</option>
            </select>

    <script>
    $(document.ready)(function(){

    //set the list from model
    var modelvalue = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ValueFromList))';

    $(#list1).val(modelvalue);

    });
//handle the change event of Dropdown list
 $("#country").change(function() 
     { 
         var _selected = $("#list1").val();
         var options = 
         {
             type: "POST",
             url: '@Url.Action("Action1","controller1")',
             data:  _selected + ,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",

             success: function(msg) {
                      //set the returned value as the selected dropdownlist value
               $(#list1).val(msg);

                 }
             }
         }; 
.ajax(options);   


    </script>
```

//this is the class that you want to set the value in (the Model)

```
Class1
{
public string ValueFromList {get;set;}

}
```

//then you need an action method ( in your Controller) that will update the Model with the new Value:

```
public Controller1
{

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Action1(string value)
{

Class1 cl1=new Class1();
cl1.ValueFromList=value;
return Json(new {Success="true", cl1});
}
```

Comment: Thank you or your answer and obviously it would work but I was hoping there was a simpler way of doing it... I mean if you can change a variable in the model using fx razor with a lambda expression, surely there must be an equally simple method to use a dropdown without having to resort to any JQuery and additional controller methods? I've actually already got it working that way my only problem is that I keep gettin a null reference error when but the objects are still built an saved in the db. Perhaps you could assist with solving the null reference bug? I will update my answer with my code.

Comment: Weird typos sry, the problem is the objects are built and saved in the db but I get a null reference error anyway?